# Edit my application settings.bundle's settings from iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings.bundle

I have created a setting.bundle in my iPhone app project. Its working fine. An application setting are visible in iPhone default Settings application with application icon and name.

I have also created a UIViewController in my app which contains the same setting functions which are in setting.bundle's Root.plist.

Means I have same setting view both in iPhone default Setting app and in my app setting viewcontroller.

When I apply some changes in iPhone default settings of my app, its reflect changes in my application from NSNotification object.

But problem occurs when I do some changes in my application settings viewcontroller, I can't apply this  changes in iPhone default setting app. I want both setting page work synchronously. Both setting page needs to reflect them changes on each other.

One logic I found is this: 
need to modify settings.bundle's Root.plist within my application, parallel with application setting viewcontroller. But How to modify it, If I will succeed in modifying it, will it effect my iPhone default setting app's settings?

Second: Is is possible to send any notifications from application to iPhone default settings application to change its value?

Help me to solve this.

If I am not succeed to explain you my issue, please ask me. I will explain you in brief.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can change the value of settings app programmatically.

You need to call `registerDefaults` for changing the settings value programmatically like:

`[defaults setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"Toggle];`

store a setting then `[defaults synchronize];` for saving the settings.

Here `Toggle` is the identifier given to any of the settings component.

2) Add your class as observer for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changed) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void) changed
{
  //change the app viewcontroller settings here
}
```

And change the viewControllers settings in the above method.

Comment: Thank you to answer.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:appDelegate.objSettings.strLang forKey:@"PSMultiValueSpecifier"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.objSettings.intervalIndex] forKey:@"PSMultiValueSpecifier"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",appDelegate.objSettings.isLetterSoundOn] forKey:@"PSToggleSwitchSpecifier"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 

I did this, to change the value. But Its not working.

Comment: Hello Miduhn, Please read above post. 
I have entered [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:appDelegate.objSettings.strLang forKey:@"PSMultiValueSpecifier"]; to save the value, but its not working.
One more question what to do if We have more than one toggle switches?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NileshTripathi: `PSMultiValueSpecifier` not the key. You will add an entry as identifier for every settings object. That's the key, not the settings key.